# Can one be cruel to nonsentient things?

Tags: ethics, philosophy-of-mind, consciousness

I recently read a paper in the journal "Analysis" titled, "Can one be cruel to a chair?". This got me thinking, can people be cruel to nonsentient objects? I believe that, while one can have harmful intentions toward nonsentient objects, one can't be cruel per se, because cruelty requires consciousness for the thing being cruel towards. But what have philosophers thought about this topic?

Comment: I wonder why do you consider this an interesting question. Could you provide some motivation or background?

Comment: @JoWehler Well, it is because, like I said in the question, I read a paper in a philosophy journal.

Comment: Robinson's paper references about 20 authors and papers. I assume that at least some of them answer your question "But what have philosophers thought about this topic?" Have you already studied these references?

Comment: I often joke about torturing SQL Server with my weird and complex crosstab report statements. But it's probably not even breaking a sweat. "*I laugh at your silly queries!*"

Comment: I would consider this an interesting question if one includes animals as things.  I have a better answer  below.

Comment: I find it strange and a little sad that the body of this post mentions a paper dedicated to answering the question at hand, yet neither the question nor any of the answers acknowledge the contents of that paper whatsoever (or any of the surrounding work, as Jo Wehler pointed out in an earlier comment).

Comment: @Carmeister if you have a link to the reference that is not in a paywall, please add it.

Comment: Ask Elvis (unless you consider hearts to be sentient).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Metaphorically, sure, but not literally. Cruelty is an indifference to pain and suffering. Objects like rocks and [trees don't suffer pain](https://www.britannica.com/story/do-plants-feel-pain). Therefore, by definition one can only be cruel to that which experiences pain and suffering.

EDIT

2024-03-25 Added link to Britannica article on why plants do NOT feel pain.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152182/discussion-on-answer-by-j-d-can-one-be-cruel-to-nonsentient-things); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: "trees don't suffer pain" I disagree. Acacia trees produce a chemical reaction when they are damaged that signals tells the ant colony living inside of the tree to come out and start attacking the thing that damaged the tree. And in fact all trees have chemical responses that travel throughout the entire tree when damaged. And they can pass that message on to neighboring trees.

Comment: @Questor Pain is generally construed as the suffering of higher-order sentient beings. There is more to the experience of suffering than chemical reactions. It requires an awareness. Trees aren't aware, and it seems a dubious claim that insects are self-aware even.

Comment: @JD What is awareness? Trees are able to send chemical signals across large areas (see birch/fig trees and mycorrhizal networks.. They are even capable of sharing nutrients thru that network. And they can send information about disease/ insect attacks/ and fires to other connected trees, which change their behavior in response to the signals...

Comment: @Questor by this definition, a person in a coma is aware. Most people not in a coma would disagree.

Comment: @Questor Well, that's simple. Kick a person in a shin, and she'll kick back. Tell a dad joke, and you might get a laugh. Insult a person's mother and see the dislike on the face of the person. Trees can do none of this. You ask the question. It's not what is awareness, but rather which form of awareness are we talking about. Cutting down a tree is not cruelty because trees are not human aware and do not suffer like higher-order animals. It's a fun theoretical exercise to stretch definitions, but terms are only so elastic before becoming absurd.

Comment: @JD I vehemently disagree on the basis that with all those examples, you are essentially defining the subjective experience of another based on your personal subjective interpretation of events which seems to be highly dissonant reasoning. Your definition would deem a person with locked in syndrome as suddenly incapable of suffering. What you describe would not be unlike a teenager being heartbroken over a trivial break-up and an adult declaring that what the teenager is feeling isn't really heartbreak on the basis no adult would be heartbroken over such a minor thing.

Comment: @DKNguyen You're free to disagree. But the criteria I listed are not exhaustive, so it's odd you would treat them as such. Your claims of dissonance seem to suggest you don't grasp defeasibility as a characteristic of reasoning.

Comment: @JD Not when it is so easy to defeat the so-called feasible reasoning.

Comment: Switch "tree" for something like "glass of water," please. Push a tree and it grows [reaction wood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_wood). Pull too many leaves and it may start producing toxins or signal neighbors; see "Condensed tannin as anti-defoliate agent against browsing by giraffe (Giraffa camelopardalis) in the Kruger National Park" (no free PDF available, sadly.) @Questor nailed it; pain nerves aren't necessary to react to damage, and plenty of plants show awareness of their surroundings. [Venus flytraps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus_flytrap) can count touches!

Comment: @JD If you judge intelligence by the ability to climb trees... Then Dolphins are imbeciles, and koalas one of the geniuses of the mammals.. With Humans barely sentient... adults less intelligent then children.

Comment: @Questor Don't be so silly. I wouldn't judge all intelligences by the ability to climb trees. I judge only tree-climbing intelligence by the ability to climb trees. And dolphins are indeed tree-climbing imbeciles. If you don't believe me, buy one and get it to climb a tree. I'd think twice before posting such silliness.

Comment: @Corbin I respect your right to belief, but it's clearly fringe. https://www.britannica.com/story/do-plants-feel-pain

Comment: @DKNguyen Unlike ['defeasible reasoning' which is a technical term (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/reasoning-defeasible/), 'feasible reasoning' is something you just made up. But if makes you feel better, you GOT ME!

Comment: @JD And yet you judge all things pain sensitivity by the pain sensitivity of things with central nervous systems... instead of their ability to detect damage and produce a response. (Which appears to be one of the primary purposes of having pain receptors). Regardless of how they do so. You don't see how you are judging all things by the same biased standard... Much how judging intelligence by tree climbing is a biased standard?

Comment: @QuestorWe do indeed have a bias towards mammals, especially people, when deciding when to use the term pain and confining it to nervous systems. You can certainly try to persuade everyone, including the various scientific communities they are wrong. Do you expect the world to accept that growing wheat to make bread is genocide? Is walking on lawns domestic violence? Plants are phototropic, but that is not the same as seeing and observing the sun. To say plants suffer pain is a category mistake. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_mistake

Answer (score 9):

One conceivable scenario is akin to the [impossibility defense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impossibility_defense) in law: Are you guilty of a crime if you are trying to murder an already dead body, convinced they are alive? After all, this is factually not even an attempt.

In many countries, the law considers this a crime nonetheless. It turns out that the law is not only concerned with factual violations, it is also concerned with the state of mind of the perpetrator. Lacking malice often mitigates the punishment, as in [imperfect self-defense](https://www.justia.com/criminal/defenses/imperfect-self-defense/); in the case of an attempt to murder a dead body, the malice is prominent enough to justify punishment even in the absence of any damaged party.

Cruelty, after all, is a state of mind. As such, it is independent of the material world, even though it usually manifests in material or psychological actions against people or animals. Therefore, a moral argument can be made regarding cruelty against objects, especially if the perpetrator assigns some degree of personhood to the object, as we humans frequently do. We become emotionally attached to objects which surround us. For example, we give them names and are sad when they break. Spiritually or esoterically inclined people may actually be delusional enough to assign personhood to objects. Needling a puppet in a Voodoo ceremony would be an example of a similar delusion, and consequently cruelty. Children may torture their dolls.

In the end, any behavior towards inanimate objects which would be considered cruel if it were animated may be considered cruel if the perpetrator draws satisfaction from it. Such behavior would expose a state of mind which is enough of a deviation from the norm to label it cruel.

Comment: When you stub your toe on something, you might react by calling it names, as if it intentionally caused your accident. Or if your car breaks down, you'll lash out at it.

Comment: @Barmar Kind of the opposite of the old, "*I refute it thus!*" idea.

Comment: This makes me think of the movie Cast Away. Imagine if someone _murdered_ Wilson.

Comment: @Barmar - [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhzckCB3Bo8)?

Answer (score 4):

Certainly! Humans have tendency to anthropomorphize things, including inanimate objects or even non-substantial things. Since, as you pointed out, cruelty requires harmful intent, not just harmful consequences per se, cruelty is subjective. As such, is perfectly reasonable to consider cruelty towards inanimate objects, as if the object had feelings that could be hurt and the person being cruel intentionally wishes to hurt the object.

Comment: Maybe we could be nicer to people too, even if we can't understand their different experience?

Comment: I had a coworker who would bring stuffed animals to work, and I always threw cruel false accusations at them.  Poor things.  But my coworker was always a step ahead of me and had an answer for everything.

Answer (score 4):

How do you define "sentience"?  Is it binary or are there degrees of sentience?

Scientists conduct experiments on "lower" animals all the time: rabbits, mice, chimpanzees, fish, clams, etc.  I recognize that there are people who are concerned about animal experimentation, and I do not discount that belief.  Some of these people object to experimentation on mammals but not on non-mammalian vertebrates, and some object to experiments on vertebrates but not invertebrates.

I recall PETA got mad when somebody wanted to study the structure of an ant's nest so he poured molten aluminum down the entrances, effectively killing every living thing in that nest.  Getting drowned in molten aluminum is a pretty quick way to die.

As I wrote my comment above, I was going to write a tautology such as "All living things are things".  You mentioned a chair.  When the trees were killed to make the wood to make a wooden chair, did they experience pain?  You cannot prove that trees do not experience pain, and I do not know how to demonstrate that they do.  All living things die, and since death is inevitable, then perhaps the state of mind of whatever kills the living thing is really what's important.

Comment: "*If a fir tree had a foot or two or a wing, like a turtle or a bird, do you think it would just stand there waiting for the saw to enter?*" - Rumi - You are correct, your state of mind is very important.

Comment: @ScottRowe If trees could scream, would we be so cavalier about cutting them down? We might, if they screamed all the time, for no good reason. -- Jack Handey :-)

Comment: @SusanW babies on a plane? I bring noise-cancelling headphones, but parents just lose their hearing, I guess. I wasn't a fan of Screaming Trees, but I liked The Ramones.

Comment: @ScottRowe I assure you, parents do *not* lose their hearing.  Please do not confuse "unaware" with "inability" or "incompetence".   Parents are aware, very aware, that their baby is screaming.  Most of the time, they are unable to do anything about it, and they have decided that the child's discomfort is worth the price compared to the alternatives.  There are incompetent parents who choose not to be aware, and there are incompetent parents who could do something but they are incompetent so they don't.

Comment: Are human babies sentient?  I had not thought of this question before now.  I thought that sentience was binary: sentient/non-sentient.  Then a range: totally non-sentient to fully sentient.  Now, a temporal component: not yet sentient/fully sentient.



I do not remember my own bris (ritual circumcision).  I have an acute memory of the bris of my son.

Comment: Ok Jeff, sorry to give offense: I meant that they **literally** experience hearing loss, which is a documented medical issue. Not that they are *ignoring* the baby. That there are situations where parents can't do anything, but have to hold the baby anyway, which is the only thing that works. As for sentience, I always think in terms of potential for increase: a guinea pig obviously can sense, respond, learn, but it will never be a dog. A dog can learn and become amazingly aware, so we should respect that, but will never be a gorilla. Children can eventually become Philosophers :-)

Comment: @Scott Rowe: I did not know that about literal hearing loss.  Thank you for the information.  That's not been my experience as a father or as a grandfather, but sometimes hearing loss occurs and we are unaware of it.  I have a 6 db hearing loss @ 2 KHz in both ears - my audiologist tells me that this is common for computer people who worked in data centers.  I was not aware of the problem until I was tested.  No offense taken.

It's painful to let a baby cry.  It's also painful to pick up a crying baby and have them vomit on the back of your shirt.

Comment: Yes, I skipped over having children. I have a sharp loss above 3 kHz in one ear, a bike tire exploded near my head while I was filling it as a child. No crickets on that side, and I can't direction locate high pitches with just one good ear, but it's not a serious impairment. Data centers, all those whirring fans I guess? We've started trying to make workers protect their hearing. Someone said, "Blindness separates you from *things* but deafness separates you from *people*."

Answer (score 3):

If "cruelty" includes *abusive behavior*, then yes- it happens all the time. My favorite example is the youtube video of a skateboarder who wipes out spectacularly, and then picks up his board and slams it against a power pole. It then bounces off and strikes him squarely in the head.

Comment: But that's not abusive behaviour in the sense we apply to people. It's gratuitous damage to the board, sure. But it's not abuse in the sense of abuse to a person. It's only abuse in the older meaning of the word of "not being used correctly".

Comment: It is notable that bad behavior has a tendency to 'redound' against the perpetrator, even without an agent to cause that. Wrong things are often wrong for multiple reasons. Being angry while using tools can result in damage to the work, which one might care about, and harm to self.

Comment: @Graham But he's doing it partly because he's anthropomorphizing the board, treating it as if it had intentionally caused the wipeout. If you kick your car when it breaks down, you're doing the same thing.

Comment: @Barmar right, the action is based on *blaming*, with an attribution that the object had a goal of harming you. The imputed motive is one step further than the cruel action, and the blame is further than that. No wonder the Buddha said we are all lost in delusion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  I think we can and do be cruel to objects.  But it is pretend cruelty.  We recognize that we are playing and pretending.

Kids blowing up GIJoe's with firecrackers, or playing Barbie and have Ken cheat on Barbie and cause a big 'ol pretend fight with blaming and crying and hurt feelings.

It is pretend, it is play, but it is also potentially practice, and desensitization.

It can also be "processing" and "working through", therapeutic.  Or "experimenting to explore scenarios and outcomes".  Researching and learning.

Or just plain old entertainment.  See how high GIJoe can fly.

The "cruelty" is there.  It is not experienced by the non-animate objects.  But it is there.  Not necessarily a bad thing, perhaps.  Sometimes we teach ourselves by viewing "What not to do" scenarios.

There is a "time-loop" plotstyle movie called Palm Springs.  In it, one scene sees one of the trapped time-loopers being cruel to a third party (which will not remember the cruelty the next day/the future.

Niles (the other person trapped looping says "Don't do that, don't be cruel".

Sarah says "Why not, nothing matters, they won't remember, this won't have happened."

Niles says "But we do.  We remember.  We see it all in our memories still.  It can't be who we are, it will change us if we become that".

Which I thought was interesting.  A puts a different spin on things when I am blowing jumbo jets out of the sky with rocket launchers or flying them into buildings playing while playing GTA5.  It makes me think about it more.  (lol)

Another movie, called Free Guy mostly takes place within a made-up for the movie virtual world game called "Free City".  This movie has AI driven non-player characters.  So the game explores their existence, and public interaction with non-player-characters.  And public reaction when they become self-aware.  Making it an interesting exploration of cruelty to "artificially sentient" identities that can't even claim the characteristic of "object" or "real" per se.

The question is interesting.

Comment: It's been shown that the mind can't distinguish actual from as-if. Also, it doesn't distinguish violence directed at another from violence impacting self. "*The self perceives all actions to be self-directed*" or something like that, I don't know how to find the exact reference just now in psych literature. So, you are sanding down your empathy and concern for other (and yourself!) with every moment of doing 'pretend' or inadvertent violent or abusive things. You are part of all that is. There is not a 'you' and a 'them'. That said, people do need to be able to try things out and practice.